# .HtAccess rewriting: Direct www.X.com to www.Y.com/test, whilst still showing www.X.com in the browser

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a domainname, www.X.com that redirects (using some magic from the webhosting-company from which I bought www.X.com) any user that visits www.X.com to www.Y.com/test.

This works fine, but what I would like to happen is for the URL to remain www.X.com after the redirect. Right now, after the redirect the users URL changes to www.Y.com/test.

I'm not sure if htaccess rewriting at www.Y.com can fix this issue, so I would like to know wether this is possible and if so, how do I implement it in my .htacces file?

Regards and thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: You'll need to use the [proxy flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) on the x.com htaccess.

Comment: Will using the proxy flag also keep the users' URL set to x.com?

Comment: That is correct. As shown in the example on that link, requesting an image on one server will actually respond with the response from another server.

Comment: Would there also be a way to achieve this effect using www.Y.com's htacces? Turns out www.X.com really is just a domainname without any webhosting attached to it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Your best bet would be to point the DNS of domain X to the same server that handles domain Y. Then you wouldn't need any rules in place. If that's circumstantially a problem, then I'm afraid there's not much you could do. (That said, I'm no server guru, so someone else may be able to step in and assist.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the redirect tool of your hosting provider. You have to configure your domain to point to your server with a `DNS A record`:

```
Domain      Type   target server
www.X.com.    A    x.x.x.x
www.Y.com.    A    x.x.x.x
```

In your server virtualhost or via your hosting provider you need to configure both domains to point to your website.

In your `.htaccess` file you need ton configure domain `www.X.com` to point to the `test` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.X.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1
```

Comment: Would the htaccess rewrite take place in the www.Y.com htacces?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by clearing out my Chrome cache; The webhost-magic HAD done the trick. Thanks mr Rockett and mr Lemaitre for your time!